# Develop Plugins for Vue TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, vue.js, tinymce

I want to develop a plugin for TinyMCE Vue extension. I am using vue-easy-tinymce and the link is [M3ESMA](https://github.com/m3esma/vue-easy-tinymce). I will use it in WordPress. Have anyone any experience or idea how can I do it?

I want to add a tab here.
[View this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBrjf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts ...

1 - the Vue/TinyMCE connector you reference has not been updated in 2 years.  TinyMCE has its own Vue connector that is actively being developed:

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue

I would recommend using that connector as its under active development.

2 - What you are asking about is really just updating an existing TinyMCE plugin - the media plugin.

If you want different/modified behavior from that plugin you can modify the source code of the plugin and use the modified version.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Actually where the plugin is required, the old connector is used. So I am bound with this connector.

I have already tried the second way you mentioned. But it is not affecting the Vue TinyMCE. Because that is different from the main plugin. I am using in WordPress.